# C - getchar and dynamically created arrays

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays, getchar, calloc

I am working on a vector class in C, and I was having some issues using `getchar()`. While I understand that `getchar()` will return an integer/unsigned char, it seems to behave differently when a value from `getchar()` is assigned to a dynamically created array in c. I have some code I was testing to show that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){ 
    char **ptr;
    ptr=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    unsigned char c = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", c); //this prints a normal value
    ptr[0] = &c;  //dereference the value to assign it to the dynamic array
    printf("%s",ptr[0]); // This prints an odd value
}
```

And here was the resulting output from this code:

```
[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4Test
g
g
g▒▒[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4Test
j
j
j▒~[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4Test
q
q
q▒[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4Test
r
r
r0▒
```

And when I tried to implement this code into my code so [far](http://pastebin.com/TnLeNsLc), it behaves even more erratically:

```
[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4

Enter the Name : kl
flag
flag
ptr[2] = (null)
ptr[2] = (null)
[jake@shell] hw4 $ ./hw4

Enter the Name : jkla
flag
flag
flag
flag
ptr[4] = (null)
ptr[4] = (null)
ptr[4] = (null)
ptr[4] = (null)
*** glibc detected *** ./hw4: free(): invalid next size (fast):                     0x0000000000705010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33cae75e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x33cae789b3]
./hw4[0x400691]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x33cae1ed5d]
./hw4[0x400529]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:13 7473045                                    /home/jlongar/Desktop/cStuff/hw4/hw4
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:13 7473045                            /home/jlongar/Desktop/cStuff/hw4/hw4
00705000-00726000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                      [heap]
33ca600000-33ca620000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 130889                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33ca81f000-33ca820000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 130889                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33ca820000-33ca821000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 130889                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
33ca821000-33ca822000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
33cae00000-33caf8a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 130934                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33caf8a000-33cb18a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 130934                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33cb18a000-33cb18e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 130934                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33cb18e000-33cb18f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 130934                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
33cb18f000-33cb194000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
33cca00000-33cca16000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 131173                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
33cca16000-33ccc15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 131173                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
33ccc15000-33ccc16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 131173                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f816bdde000-7f816bde1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f816bdf5000-7f816bdf9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff85e61000-7fff85e76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff85f62000-7fff85f63000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                      [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

how can I make getchar play nicely with dynamically created arrays in C?

Comment: `getchar` **does** play nicely. It is your responsiobility to get the types right. Why do you use a _pointer to pointer to char_?

Comment: Rather than `char **ptr; ptr=calloc(10,sizeof(char));`, I'd use `char **ptr;
    ptr=calloc(10, sizeof *ptr);`   `sizeof(char)` is wrong or type of `ptr` is wrong`.

Comment: There seems to be some mis-understaning.  `C` does not have `class`es.  It does have `functions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the types right it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *ptr = calloc(10, 1);  // sizeof(char) is ALWAYS 1
    unsigned char c = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", c); //this prints a normal value
    ptr[0] = c;  //dereference the value to assign it to the dynamic array
    printf("%c", ptr[0]); // This prints an odd value
    free(ptr);
}
```

First rule of programming, do not over-complicate things.  Why use a pointer to pointer (**) when you can use just one level of indirection - a pointer (*).

Second rule of programming, match types correctly.  See the differences with your code above.  Also note in the printf format string, the contents of ptr[0] is a char, not a char*.

Comment: _"match types correctly"_ Which is why, when using `malloc` & co, it's best to infer the size of the type using the pointer itself (`calloc(10, sizeof *ptr);` is guaranteed to be correct)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is the last *printf()*.**

---

*ptr[0]* represents a pointer to *char*, so if you want to print it's content you have to dereference it.

So, you have to change *printf("%s",ptr[0]);* with **printf("%c", *ptr[0])**.

You see, it's **%c**. That's again, because **ptr[0]** is **pointer to char**, so ***ptr[0]** is **char**.

Finally, change your code to this, and you'll get the result you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char **ptr;
    ptr=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    char c = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", c);
    ptr[0] = &c;
    printf("%c",*ptr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```